# do I have to upgrade all servers to 2016 at once?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2003, upgrade, windows-server-2016

Do I?

Currently, we have a mix of 2003, 2008, 2008R2 and 2012.
I want to move to 2016 AD for DCs only.
I'm going to purchase CALs and Server 2016 Standard licenses.

I assume not?

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't have to per se. There are however certain software packages that cannot coexist:

- Exchange 2003 cannot coexist with Exchange 2013+
- 2003 DC cannot coexist with 2016 DC, you [need a domain functionality level of at least 2008](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server-docs/identity/ad-ds/windows-server-2016-functional-levels?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)